# Running 6 LEDs off 3s (12.6v) and 4s (16.2v) battery

Tags: led, pcb, voltage-regulator, pcb-design

This may be a very simple question but I want to run 6 LEDs on a PCB and I know I can run them simply off a 12.6v 3s battery but if I want to run a 4s battery 16.2 then I will need some sort of switching regulator but space is an issue and a high efficiency switching regulator will be expensive and large.

Is there a method I can look into that will also provide the correct voltage at 12.6/16.2v?

Comment: What size of LED?  Standard 5mm or 3mm LEDs running at 20mA or less *OR* large LEDs (1 Watt or more)?  Makes a huge difference as to the techniques that you might use.

Comment: Also note that you are spedifying fully-charged voltage on the battery rather than the normal operating voltage of 3.6V or 3.7V per cell.  This doesn't matter if you are using active current limit but will affect LED current (and brightness) if just using simple series resistors.

Answer (score 1):

LEDs always have their operating point set via some current limiting device. Typically this is just a resistor in series with each string of LEDs. If you measure the current that your LEDs draw on 3S then you can calculate the extra resistance required to run then on 4S.

The difference between 12.6V and 16.8V is 4.2V. If the total current draw of all 6 LEDs on your pcb is (for example) 100mA at 12.6V then use Ohm's law (resistance = voltage / current) to calculate the resistance required to drop 4.2V at 100mA. 4.2V/0.1A = 42 Ohms. The nearest standard 5% values are 39 Ohms and 47 Ohms, either of which should be OK.

The only other thing to be concerned about is heat in the resistor. Watts = Volts x Amps, so with a fully charged battery that 42 Ohm resistor would dissipate 4.2V x 0.1A = 0.42 Watts. For safety you would choose a resistor rated at 1W or higher.